# removing GET parameters from URL Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, get, multilingual

I have multilanguage installed on my spring app, and I don't want the 'lang' parameter to appear in the URL (I'm storing the locale with sessionLocaleResolver or cookieLocaleResolver/neither works).
I've searched for hours to find a solution to this issue, although apparently it should already be working with what I've done. Here's my code :

The view (welcome.jsp) :

```
Language : <a href="?lang=en">English</a>|<a href="?lang=fr_FR">Francais</a>|<a href="?lang=ro_RO">Romanian</a>
<h2>welcome.springmvc : <spring:message code="welcome.text" text="default text" /></h2>
```

My servlet.xml

```
    <!-- Multi-Language / Localization Setup -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:lang.files/welcome</value>
            <!-- <value>classpath:messages2</value> -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="60000" />
    <property name="cookiePath" value="/" />
</bean>
```

My Controller code - note that I'm staying in the same page when I click on the link to change the language. Because ideally it would be a dropdown, and I'd stay in the same page

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    String message = "<br/ ><div style='text-align:center;'>"
            + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3></div><br />";

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    // ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(new
    // RedirectView("welcome.do", true, true, true));
    RedirectView view = new RedirectView("/welcome", true);
    view.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
    mv.setView(view);

    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("activities", activityService.getAll());
    mv.addObject("act", activityService.getR());

    return new ModelAndView(view);
}
```

The result is a '404' saying that 'localhost/myapp/welcome' is not found.

Finally this the controller, working, but adding the 'lang' parameter in the URL :

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    String message = "<br/ ><div style='text-align:center;'>"
            + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3></div><br />";

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("activities", activityService.getAll());
    mv.addObject("act", activityService.getR());

    return mv;
}
```

Please help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    String message = "<br/ ><div style='text-align:center;'>"
            + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3></div><br />";

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    // ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(new
    // RedirectView("welcome.do", true, true, true));
    RedirectView view = new RedirectView("/welcome", true);
    view.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
    mv.setView(view);

    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("activities", activityService.getAll());
    mv.addObject("act", activityService.getR());

    return new ModelAndView(view);
}
```

This code causes an infinite loop as you are redirecting to /welcome over and over again.

Moreover when you've got a link like `<a href="?lang=en">English</a>` the parameter will always appear in the url when you click on it.

The easiest way(not best) to achieve the goal you want is to create another controller method  like

```
@RequestMapping("/changeLocale")
public ModelAndView changeLocale() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/welcome");
    redirectView.setExposePathVariables(false);
    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
}
```

And links will look like

```
<a href="/changeLocale?lang=en">English</a>|<a href="/changeLocale?lang=fr_FR">Francais</a>|<a href="/changeLocale?lang=ro_RO">Romanian</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I managed to get it working using your help, and whilst I'm not proficient in Spring MVC,I I'll be able to advance with my project using ur guidelines.  Best of whishes :)